# packer templates and conditional statements

Tags: packer

I'd like to use conditional statements in the packer template at the "provisioners" stage.

```
  "provisioners": [
    {
      "execute_command": "echo 'vagrant'|sudo -S sh '{{.Path}}'",
      "override": {
        "virtualbox-iso": {
          "scripts": [
            "scripts/base.sh",
            "scripts/puppet.sh",
          ]
        }
      },
      "type": "shell",
    }
  ]
```

For instance, if the user, at the "packer build" command line, specifies, somehow, a "puppet" parameter then then the "scripts/puppet.sh" will be executed otherwise skipped.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think that this is possible with packers native template formate, because packer uses the JSON format for configuration which  as long as I know does not support flow control mechanisms like the conditional statement. But it should be possible to archive a similar behaviour with a [user variables](https://www.packer.io/docs/templates/legacy_json_templates/user-variables) and the shell provisioner.

### The idea

The easiest way should be to set a user variable from the build command and [pass this variables from packer to the shell provisioner](https://packer.io/docs/provisioners/shell.html#environment_vars) script which detects the value of the user variable and calls the appropriate provisioner script e.g. puppet, salt,...

### Disclaimer:

I didn't test this approach, but it should give you a hint to what I mean and maybe you can come up with an even better solution. ;-)

### The problem solving approach

**1. Define the variable which indicates the used provisioner:**

There are multiple ways to define a user variable,

- by calling the packer build command with the -var flag (see end of answere)
- define the user variables in the box-template file

  ```
  The packer box template file: **template.json**

       "variables": [
           "using_provision_system": "puppet"
       ]
       "provisioners": [
            {...}
  ```
- define a variable definition file and specify the path to it in the build command with -var-file

  ```
  The variable file: **variables.json**
  Is a great alternative if you want to define variables in a seperate file.

       {
          "using_provision_system": "puppet"
       }
  ```

**2. Calling the shell script which calls the provisioner scripts:**

Now modify the execute_command in a way that the 'master' script is called with the defined variable as argument.

```
"provisioners": [
    {
      "execute_command": "echo 'vagrant'|sudo -S sh '{{.Path}}' '{{user `using_provision_system`}}'",
      "override": {
        "virtualbox-iso": {
          "scripts": [
            call_provisioner_script.sh
          ]
        }
      },
      "type": "shell",
    }
  ]
```

Notice, we only need to specify one script. This one 'master' script takes  the passed variable as argument and compares the value with some predefined provisioner names in a switch condition.
(Short: It chooses which provisioner scripts will be executed.)

master provision script: **call_provisioner_script.sh**

```
case $1 in
    puppet*) sh puppet_provisioner.sh
    *) sh shell_provisioner.sh
```

**Take care!**
Because this script will run inside your box, you might need to upload the scripts to the box before this command gets executed.

**3. Last step is to build your box :)**

Calling packers build command:

```
#define variable in build command (first option from above)
$ packer build -var 'using_provision_system=puppet' template.json

#define variables in variable file and set path in build command
$ packer build -var-file=variables.json template.json
```

Instead of using user variables, there should maybe a way to set enviromental variables in your box and use this type of variable to specify the provisioner.

Comment: Has this changed now that we have HCL2 for packer?

Comment: I haven't touched packer for quite some time and I'm not familiar with HCL, but it's seems like that [only/except](https://www.packer.io/docs/templates/hcl_templates/onlyexcept) could be the right thing. It should then be similar to @jeffreyveon's answere. E.g. create one provision configuration for the base scripts (has only=["base"] set) and another for puppet which has `only=["base" "puppet"]` set. Then running packer with `-only=base,puppet` as cli-argument should run `base` and `puppet` provisioning steps. At least that is what I would expect :)

Comment: Alternatively set `only=["puppet" "salt"...]` for the base provisioner and `only=["puppet"]` for the puppet one. Then it should be sufficient to run both provisioners (base and puppet) with `packer -only=puppet`.

Answer (score 7):

An alternative way is to define 2 different builders which are of the same type but having different names. You can then exclude a provisioning step from a specific build using the `only` field:

```
{
  "source": "foo.txt",
  "destination": "/opt/foo.txt",
  "type": "file",
  "only": ["docker-local"]
}
```